Library or API for endpoint social media classification
Is there any library or API that can classify an URL and provide its specialized metadata? Those data are further extracted from standard metadata names, Open Graph metadata and other elements from the page. It doesn't have to fetch the data, I can provide the HTML myself.
Example 1:
classify('https://www.facebook.com/facebook')
// {
//   platformName: 'Facebook',
//   platformType: 'Forum',
//   endpoint: {
//     name: 'facebook',
//     type: 'page',
//     bio: 'Interet company',
//     about: 'Community Values\n\nWe believe people can do more together than alone and that each of us...'
//     createdDate: 'Nov 8, 2007'
//   } 
// } 

Example 2:
classify('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0jRX0xq24AU')
// {
//   platformName: 'YouTube',
//   platformType: 'Forum',
//   endpoint: {
//     name: 'The Story of Pasta Grannies',
//     type: 'video',
//     description: 'Food writer Vicky Bennison started her channel as a way to catalogue the traditional handmade pasta skills of Italy’s...'
//     uploadedDate: 'Oct 25, 2019'
//   } 
// } ```

